# Center tds in tr in html table (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, html-table

I want to make a table that has different amount of columns in each row and to center those columns so it would look nice.

What I currently have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Each red square will have a button.

Is this even possible with a table?

I tried to make a different table for each row, but there's a large spacing between each table so it doesn't look nice.

I'm using Bootstrap table.

This is the html code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="filled">Mark</button>
    </th>
    <th>
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="empty">Unmark</button>
    </th>
    <th>
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="unknown">Unknown</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="undo">Undo</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="redo">redo</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it cant not be done with table! Why dont you do it with DIV ?

Comment: I'll try with divs then @SifatulIslam

Comment: If you aren't doing HTML for email; an alternative modern option could be to use flex box and ditch tables. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. Using justify-content: center  for each row. Use that with your divs.

Comment: @kuhaku let me know if you need help!